# Why isn't this Google font working?

Tags: html, css, ssl, google-font-api

Have this line on my  label and is working properly on a Debian server under Apache, but when I uploaded it to my production server (Debian with Apache too) i cannot get the Open Sans Condensed font.

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:700,300,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Here's the entire :

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
        <title> XLS and CSV Conversor</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=0.5 maximum-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi">
        <meta name="description" content="Conversor CSV">
        <meta name="keywords" content="conversor CSV, conversor, CSV">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css" />
        <script src="style/sweet_alert/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/sweet_alert/sweetalert.css">
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/progressbar.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/textareascript.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.04022.js"></script>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:700,300,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <style>
                .content{
                    height: auto;
                    margin: 0;
                }
                .content div {
                    position: relative;
                }
            </style>
        <![endif]-->

         <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
         <![endif]-->
    </head>
```

Can someone tell me why? Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide either the URL or the full HTML?

Comment: Here's the entire header. This code is working properly on my development server, but at my production server the Open Sans Condensed font is not showing up. The "link href" is not working.

Comment: Are you using SSL on the production server?

Comment: @kittykittybangbang yes, I can see the padlock at the address bar. That make any difference? :O

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using SSL, you won't be able to call the non-encrypted version of Google Fonts. To fix, locate this line on your HTML page (or template):

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Whatever:400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

and change it to this:

```
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Whatever:400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

This will allow the browser to choose the appropriate page.